# How to process a text in order to create a new array with some sub strings?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a script on html, the idea is that I want to process a text that looks like this:

```
"TW|223SDSDr33|Archive" "Yes"
"TW|ASFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"TW|AFFSFSFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"TW|12AFFFSDFASFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"TW|FSFASFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"TW|AFFSDFAASFSA|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"TW|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"
```

I want to process the text to create an array called words, that contains substrings of the previous text using the pipe as separator as follows:

```
words=["TW,223SDSDr33,Archive" "Yes",...,"TW,sfasfsSFSAFAS,AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"]
```

In order to achieve this, I tried:

```
var stringArray = document.getElementById("texto").value.split('\n');
document.write(stringArray.toString());
var arrayLength = stringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    //Process every line;
}
```

This save my textarea to then process it, but the problem is that I don't know how to process every line in order to extract the sub strings that I want, In order to be more clear this is the complete code, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to achieve this, thanks thanks anyhow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<textarea cols=150 rows=10 id="texto">
"TW|223SDSDr33|Archive" "Yes"
"TW|ASFFSDFSFASDFS|Name" "LOCALggr"
"TW|AFFSFSFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckAssocCd" ""
"TW|12AFFFSDFASFSFASDFS|AFFAckCommID" "fsdf"
"TW|FSFASFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckLevel" "fsdf Supported"
"TW|AFFSDFAASFSA|AFFAckRqst" "No Requedfst"
"TW|AFFSDFSFASDFS|AFFAckTestInd" "Test"
"TW|sfasfsSFSAFAS|AFFAckVersion" "fsdfs"

</textarea>

<script>
var words = [];
var stringArray = document.getElementById("texto").value.split('\n');
document.write(stringArray.toString());
var arrayLength = stringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    //Do something;
}




</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the text is guaranteed to be in this format then it seems pretty straight-forward; your string consists of two chunks wrapped in double-quotes, the first of which is pipe-delimited. What's the specific issue?

Comment: The specific issue is that I don't know how to split these  strings "TW|223SDSDr33|Archive" "Yes", using the pipe as separator to later store it in an array.

Comment: Hm, I see. Well, I'd suggest at least trying *something*, noting that splitting on the pipe is trivial, so really the issue is how to differentiate between the two quoted "chunks".

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I believe that I need to construct a regular expression.

Comment: Did the reply help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used both a regular expression and `Array.prototype.split`. You can uncomment depending what you want to put into `words`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var line = stringArray[i];
    var quotes = /"(.*?)" "(.*?)"/.exec(line);
    if (quotes) {
      var first = quotes[1];
      var last = quotes[2];

      var separated = first.split("|");

      // If you want to put the array of words
      words.push(separated);

      // In case you want them joined with a colon
      // words.push(separated.join(","));

      // If you want to add the second word that was in double quotes
      // words.push(last);
    }
}

// Uncomment to see results
// console.log(words);
```